# pip install robotframework-desktoplibrary : failed. Why can't install?

Tags: installation, robotframework, desktop

I tried to install desktoplibrary but get the error below :

```
pip install robotframework-desktoplibrary

Collecting robotframework-desktoplibrary
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/dc/02d773cb2a052a77b226
e11a7104d506ecb827798bb4395757104eb0118f/robotframework-desktoplibrary-1.0.1.zip
 (15.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.6MB 1.7MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sqaadmin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.e
xe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sqaadmin
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-1m3ui56u\\robotframework-desktoplibrary\\
setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sqaadmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-i
nstall-1m3ui56u\\robotframework-desktoplibrary\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize
, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'
"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-ba
se 'C:\Users\sqaadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-1m3ui56u\robotframework-d
esktoplibrary\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\sqaadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-1m3ui56u\robotf
ramework-desktoplibrary\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\sqaadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-1m3ui56u\robotfra
mework-desktoplibrary\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        execfile(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), 'target', 'src', 'SikuliLibrar
y', 'version.py'))
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

The library being installed does not support Python3. "execfile" python function it uses in its setup.py file is deprecated in python3 and thus, you get this sort of error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to test a windows desktop perhaps use windappdriver with the Desktop library portion of https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba